# gcloud auth login localhost redirect failed

Tags: gcloud

Tried to use "gcloud auth login" and got this error.

[gcloud auth login error msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFMLm.jpg)

and browser shows localhost:8085 can't be connected.

Comment: After I change my MacOS python environment from 2.x to 3.x, and everything goes find.

Answer (score 2):

I had docker running with a container using port 8085.

After killing the container, it stopped using port 8085 and auth worked again.

One trick you can use to see what is running on that port is:

```
lsof -i -n -P | grep 8085
```

For me it was docker, for you it can be a different process.

To solve this, I would do the following:

- Check if you have something running on port 8085 `lsof -i -n -P | grep 8085` (note, you can do `sudo` at the start but not recommend it)
- Kill the process running in that port.
- Run your auth again.

Answer (score 1):

Clear browsers cache and re-try, it should work. I had same issue. It worked after browsers cache clear.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).